# Final outputs aren't printing after inputting values

Tags: python

I'm new to lists in python and trying to write a code where one inputs 10 numbers using a list and the following is performed:

- Copy the number which is even to a new list named "EvenList" and
  output that new list.
- Output the average of the numbers stored in the new list.

Here is my code:

```
List=[]
EvenList=[]
totalnum=0
count=0
for i in range(10):
    List.append(int(input("Enter a number: ")))
    
    while List[i]%2==0:
        EvenList.append(List[i])
        totalnum=totalnum+List[i]
        count=count+1


print(EvenList)
average=totalnum/count
print("Average: ", average)
```

Whenever I run this module, after inputting my values my outputs (both the EvenList and average) aren't printed. Here's the output I get:

Example 1:

```
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 2
```

Example 2:

```
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 2
```

By further analysis, I realized whenever an even number was inputted, that's when the code gave an empty output. So I'm speculating my error lies in line 8 - 11 (there may be even more).

I so far changed my inital code:
`List[i]=int(input("Enter a number: "))` and `EvenList[index]=(List[i])`
to
`List.append(int(input("Enter a number: ")))` and `EvenList.append(List[i])` respectively - which I'm still confused as to why the intial code isn't considered to be correct since I thought they did the exact same thing [if someone could explain, it'd be very appreciated] - but that didn't fix this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because in while loop condition, if the number is even it gets stuck in infinite loop, instead of while add if:

```
List=[]
EvenList=[]
totalnum=0
count=0
for i in range(10):
    List.append(int(input("Enter a number: ")))
    
    if List[i]%2==0:
        EvenList.append(List[i])
        totalnum=totalnum+List[i]
        count=count+1


print(EvenList)
average=totalnum/count
print("Average: ", average)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's alternative using *list comprehension*, `sum()`, and `len()` as substitutes of creating `EvenList`, `totalnum`, `count`, and `average` :

```
List = [int(input("Enter a number: ")) for i in range(10)]
EvenList = [i for i in List if i % 2 == 0]
average = sum(EvenList)/len(EvenList)
print(EvenList); print("Average: ", average)
```

Or *list comprehension in list comprehension*:

```
EvenList = [i for i in [int(input("Enter a number: ")) for i in range(10)] if i % 2 == 0]
average = sum(EvenList)/len(EvenList)
print(EvenList); print("Average: ", average)
```